# React native not refresh screens when navigate navigation drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I develop a app use navigation drawer.that navigate screens use navigation drawer.but that screens are not refresh when navigate.how i fix this

Comment: Please show your code snippet for better understanding of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following code in your `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.subs = this.props.navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      //Your logic, this listener will call when you open the class every time }
    );
  }
```

And don't remember to remove listener in `componentWillUnmount()`,

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subs.remove();
  }
```

Comment: I solved it.then i need to refresh same screen use navigation drawer.but when i click now open screen link in navigation drawer,i couldn't get any response.how i do it.

Comment: have got your solution @udithachaturanga ?